# Run soap tests from Main class

Tags: maven, jar, soapui, program-entry-point

I have maven project, which contains xml description of soap-tests (they generated from SoapUI Pro) in the root directory. I'm trying to create executable .jar file with Main class. But I don't know what to send in the Main class. Please help! )

Comment: Not sure of the question. Please if this is relevant - https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll try!